# Neovim in GNOME-terminal with mouse disabled moves cursor when scrolled

Tags: neovim, mousewheel, gnome-terminal

I'm using Neovim in the GNOME-terminal with the `mouse=` option set to disable all mouse features. This is the way I want it as I don't want the mouse moving my cursor in general.

When I use the mouse scroll wheel, whatever event the terminal is sending is moving the cursor up and down. I would rather have the scroll wheel activate real scrolling (like `<C-y>` and `<C-e>`), which is what happens if `mouse=a`. Note that I do NOT want to enable Neovim's mouse handling with `mouse=a` or similar.

How do I modify the behavior of Vim when it gets whatever event the terminal is sending when I use the mouse scroll wheel and Neovim's mouse handling is disabled?

Neovim 0.9.1 under Fedora.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This behaviour is caused by one's terminal emulator mapping the scroll functionality to the arrow keys. You can add the following lines to your configuration to disable all mouse interaction with Neovim (in certain modes):

For Lua (`.lua`):

```lua
vim.opt.mouse = ""
vim.keymap.set({ "", "i" }, "<up>", "<nop>")
vim.keymap.set({ "", "i" }, "<down>", "<nop>")
```

To enable "real scrolling", simply change the right-hand side mapping (i.e. `<nop>`) to `<c-y>` and `c-e` for the `<up>` and `<down>` keys, respectively.

For VimL (`.vim`)

```
set mouse=
noremap <Up> <nop>
inoremap <Up> <nop>
noremap <Down> <nop>
inoremap <Down> <nop>
```

To find what map modes exist, see `:h map-table`.

---

Note: mapping a key to `<nop>` means that the key will no longer perform an operation. If you require the `<up>` and `<down>` keys to retain their original functionality, while still disabling the mouse scroll functionality, you'll likely have to look at modifying the behaviour of your terminal emulator.

Comment: This disables up and down arrow keys as well.

Comment: @Friedrich Yes, bar changing the behaviour of one's terminal emulator, I don't believe there is another option? I can't remember the last time I used arrow keys in Neovim (some keyboards don't even have them). I doubt for most Vim/Neovim users those keys would be missed as the main point of the application is to have efficient keyboard-centric movement/actions. The arrow keys are very far from the home row so getting out of the habit of relying on them in Vim/Neovim is probably a good idea.

Comment: @Friedrich Also, my answer includes the option to change to RHS mapping to `<c-y>` and `<c-e>` to keep some level of arrow-key functionality enabled. Either solution addresses the OP's question (which does not list a requirement for the arrow key functionality to remain untouched). If there's a better way you have in mind, I'm happy to learn.

Comment: Disabling two keys is a side effect worth mentioning. This is what I did, not more, not less, because your answer doesn't. The decision whether or not to accept this tradeoff is left to the OP.

Comment: Great answer. It's working great for me. Turns out that I don't use up/down arrows in vim, so I don't even notice them being remapped. Appreciate your thoroughness.